# Steinitz's exchange lemma: what is its significance?

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

The Steinitz's exchange lemma I am referring here is for finitely generated (additive) abelian groups.

> Let $\{u_1,u_2,\ldots, u_n\}$ be an independent set of elements in an abelian group $A$ (i.e. their $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination is $0$ only if all coefficients are $0$). If $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_m\}$ is another set of elements of $A$ such that each $u_i$ is integral combination of $v_i$'s, then

i) $n\le m$.

ii) Among $v_i$'s, we can replace $n$ members - say with no loss $v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n$ - by all $u_i$'s so that $\{u_1,\ldots, u_n, v_{n+1}, \ldots, v_m\}$  and $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_m\}$ generate the same subgroup of $A$.

The common consequence of this lemma is shown that any two bases of finitely generated free abelian groups have same cardinality.

**Question:** Can one tell some other applications of exchange lemma beyond comparison of **sizes**  of generating sets? (I did not find in any resources such things.)

If we formulate it for vector spaces, it implies that any two bases of a finitely generated vector space have same elements; but, can't we deduce any other properties of vector spaces? Is it not used for other purpose than showing equality of sizes of bases?